# OpenCL - Writing to the Buffer is zero?

Tags: c, struct, kernel, buffer, opencl

I have written a kernel, which should be doing nothing, except from adding an one to each component of a float3:

```
__kernel void GetCellIndex(__global Particle* particles) {

   int globalID = get_global_id(0);
   particles[globalID].position.x += 1;
   particles[globalID].position.y += 1;
   particles[globalID].position.z += 1;
};
```

with following struct (in the kernel)

```
typedef struct _Particle
{
    cl_float3 position;
}Particle;
```

my problem is, that when i write my array of particles to the GPU, every component is zero. here is the neccassary code:

```
(Particle*) particles = new Particle[200];
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    particles[i].position.x = 5f;
}

cl_Particles = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(Particle)*200, NULL, &err);
if (err != 0)
{
    std::cout << "CreateBuffer does not work!" << std::endl;
    system("Pause");
}

clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, cl_Particles, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(Particle) * 200, &particles, 0, NULL, NULL);


//init of kernel etc.



err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(Particle) * 200, &cl_Particles);
if (err != 0) {
    std::cout << "Error: setKernelArg 0 does not work!" << std::endl;
    system("Pause");
}
```

and this is my struct on the CPU:

```
typedef struct _Particle
{
    cl_float4 position;
}Particle;
```

can someone help me with this problem? 
(any clue is worth to discuss...)

Thanks

Comment: 1) Maybe size of gives you size of the pointer, 2) Maybe   cl_float3 needs to be replaced by   cl_float4 in device side because of drivers or hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet contains some typical C programming errors. At first,

```
(Particle*) particles = new Particle[200];
```

does not declare a new variable `particle` as a pointer to `Particle`. It must be:

```
Particle *particles = new Particle[200];
```

As next, in your call of

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, cl_Particles, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(Particle) * 200, &particles, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

you passed a pointer to the `particles` pointer as the 6th parameter (`ptr`). But, here you must pass a pointer to the region on the host containing the data. Thus, change `&particles` to `particles`:

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, cl_Particles, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(Particle) * 200, particles, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

The setup of the kernel arguments is also wrong. Here, you must pass the OpenCL buffer created with `clCreateBuffer`. Thus, replace

```
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(Particle) * 200, &cl_Particles);
```

with:

```
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_Particle), &cl_Particles);
```

As `clCreateBuffer` returns a value of type `cl_mem`, the expression `sizeof(cl_Particle)` evaluates to the same as `sizeof(cl_mem)`. I recommend to always call `sizeof()` on the variable, so you need to change the data-type only in one place: the variable declaration.

On my platform, `cl_float3` is the same as `cl_float4`. This might not be true on your/every platform, so you should always use the same type in the host code and in the kernel code. Also, in your kernel code you should/must use the type `float4` instead of `cl_float4`.

I hope, I got the C calls right because I actually tested it with this C++ code. This code snippet contains the fixed C calls as comments:

```
Particle *particles = new Particle[200];
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    //particles[i].position.x = 5f;
    particles[i].position.s[0] = 0x5f; // due to VC++ compiler
}

//cl_mem cl_Particles = cl_createBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(Particle)*200, NULL, &err); // FIXED
cl::Buffer cl_Particles(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(Particle)*200, NULL, &err); 
checkErr(err, "Buffer::Buffer()");

//err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, cl_Particles, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(Particle) * 200, particles, 0, NULL, NULL); // FIXED
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(cl_Particles, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(Particle) * 200, particles, NULL, NULL);
checkErr(err, "ComamndQueue::enqueueWriteBuffer()");

//init of kernel
cl::Kernel kernel(program, "GetCellIndex", &err);
checkErr(err, "Kernel::Kernel()");

//err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_Particle), &cl_Particles); // FIXED
err = kernel.setArg(0, sizeof(cl_Particles), &cl_Particles);
checkErr(err, "Kernel::setArg()");
```